# In the $200 price range, which GPU maker is better Nvidia or AMD?

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop

In $200 price range, should I be looking at cards from AMD or Nvidia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this price range you have a few options:

1. From **Nvidia**: You really only have one option right now. *Note if your going for Nvidia I **highly** recommend waiting for the new Pascal based GPUs.*

   - The **[GTX 960](https://pcpartpicker.com/part/gigabyte-video-card-gvn960g1gaming4gd)**. *Although the link is to a Gigabyte card you are free to choose from any manufacturer*.
2. From **AMD**: You have a few options but by far the best is the following:

   - **[R9 380](https://pcpartpicker.com/part/asus-video-card-strixr9380dc2oc4g)**. AMD's top card in this price range. I'm a sucker for the STRIX branding but you can use whichever you would like.

**In Conclusion**

So those two are the clear winners in each category, but out of the two I cannot pose a clear winner. If you would like to see a nice head to head I recommend checking out this one [here](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-R9-380-vs-GeForce-GTX-960).